# Installing Xcode 3.2.5 on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

This is my systems software config.

- System Version:  Mac OS X 10.6 (10A432)
- Kernel Version:  Darwin 10.0.0

i am trying to install xcode 3.2.5 but it says that  need 10.6.4. What is the latest version that i can use with installation and i think 10.6 is snow leopard so this version should work. but i m a very very new as far as mac is concerned and know close to nothing. so please any pointers as to what i should do would be greatly appreciated.

regards,
khizar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 10.6.4 or later.  Upgrade from your 10.6.x to the latest version of 10.6, the upgrade is free, just select "Software Update..." from the Apple menu.

Comment: ok thanx for the quick response,i will do that... just one question, if i download and install xcode 3.1.4, how backward a step would that be?? i mean right now i am looking to start iphone dev so would it be too different from the newer version?

Comment: The Xcode 4.x GUI is substantially different but the projects are compatible so you can switch later with no problems.  Unless there is some reason to use 3.2.5 I would suggest using the latest version you can, 4.2 if possible and use ARC.  ARC is backward compatible to iOS 4.x (with the exception of wear linking zeroing).

Comment: thanx alot for the responses, although i dun get much of wat u said at the end , but i hope to once i get started :) . so i would upgrade and use the latest xcode.thanx alot :)

Comment: ARC is Automatic Reference Counting, that means that you do not write and retain, release or autorelease code, the compiler does all that behind the scenes for you.  Google ARC.  Currently you need to be a registered ($99) developer to obtain Xcode 4.2 (which supports ARC) because it is not released yet and still under NDA.

Comment: got it :) quiet simple when you put it that way :)